# Need proper method to join/merge/concat two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have read thru docs and example, but can't find what I need to solve the following problem. I need to be able join/merge/concat two dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]} 
# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df.set_index(['Name'], inplace=True)
df.head(10)

       Age
Name    
Tom     20
nick    21
krish   19
jack    18

other_data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'nick', 'nick','nick'],'Event':['event1', 'event2', 'event3','event1', 'event2', 'event3']} 
df_other = pd.DataFrame(other_data)

df_other.set_index(['Name'], inplace=True)
df_other.head(10)

         Event
Name    
Tom     'event1'
Tom     'event2'
Tom     'event3'
nick    'event1'
nick    'event2'
nick    'event3'

**Desired output:**
       Age  Event
Name
Tom     20  'event1'
Tom     20  'event2'
Tom     20  'event3'
nick    21  'event1'
nick    21  'event2'
nick    21  'event3'
krish   19   Nan
jack    18   Nan
```

I've tried many variants and either getting wrong merge/concat/join or errors

Comment: `df.join(df_other, how='left')`

Comment: @yatu That works, but joining to "df" above again with another dataframe causes an error

```
more_data = {'Name':['jack', 'jack', 'jack', 'krish', 'krish','krish'],'Event':['event1', 'event2', 'event3','event1', 'event2', 'event3']} 
df_other_more = pd.DataFrame(more_data)
df_other_more.set_index(['Name'], inplace=True)
df_other_more.head(10)

df_total = df_total.join(df_other_more, how='left')
df_total.head(20)

ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Event'], dtype='object')

```

Any thoughts?